# FactoryGirl Validation failed: Email has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have next code:
My users_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::Be::UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  setup do
    admin = FactoryGirl.create :admin

    store = FactoryGirl.create(:store, admin: admin)
    store.ug_default = UgDefault.new
    store.save

    customer = FactoryGirl.create :customer
    customer.store_id = store.id
    customer.save
  end

  test "should show user" do
    get :show, store_id: store.id, u: admin.u_token
    assert_response :success

    json = response.body
    data = JSON.parse(json)

    assert_equal 'ok', data['status']
  end

end
```

In my sequences:

```
sequence :email do |n|
    "email-#{n}@example.com"
  end
```

And my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin do
  end
end
```

And

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :store do
    admin
    name {generate :string}
    subdomain {generate :string}
    linked_domain {generate :string}
  end
end
```

And

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :customer do
  end
end
```

And

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name {generate :string}
    last_name {generate :string}
    email {generate :email}
    password_digest {generate :password_digest}
    login_attempts 1
    company_name {generate :string}
    phone {generate :string}
    u_token 'u'
  end
end
```

`Admin` and `Customer` inherited from `User`.
Now I have `Validation failed: Email has already been taken` error in line `customer = FactoryGirl.create :customer`. I've tried to clean database. rake `db:test:prepare` didn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can it be that your `:admin` and `:customer` factories does not inherit from your `:user` factory? Does it work if your `:admin` and `:customer` factories are defined like this?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :admin, parent: :user do
  end

  factory :customer, parent: :user do
  end
end
```

Comment: thx, buy now I have ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Admin(#79763910) expected, got User(#-620843828) error. how to fix it?

Comment: Oh, they are different classes. Does it work if you add `class: Admin` to the factory declaration so it reads: `factory :admin, parent: :user, class: Admin do`?

If not, you should add `email {generate :email}` to both the `:admin` and `:customer` factories.